# Exclude part of the URL via Regex Pattern in Data Studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio

I want to exclude all the URLs with customer-details part in the URL

example/d/(no customer-details part)

example/d/customer-details

I am using this regex pattern mentioned below. I am getting an error from data studio - system error.

```
CASE 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Page path, "example/d/^(?!.*(customer-details/))") THEN "Example Selection"
```

Let me know if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: 1) `^` inside a pattern without `m` flag renders the pattern useless as it won't match any string, 2) RE2 library does not support lookaheads.

Comment: Ok noted. What solution do you recommend to solve this?

Comment: You want to fail the regex match if there is `customer-details/` anywhere after `example/d/`, don't you?

Comment: Yes correct. Yes I want to fail the regex match if there is customer-details/

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the `^` anchor in the middle of the pattern and replace the negative lookahead with a negated character class based pattern since the RE2 library does not support lookarounds:

```
example/d/([^c]|c(c|u(c|s(c|t(c|o(c|m(c|e(c|r(c|-(c|d(c|e(c|t(c|a(c|i(c|l(c|sc)))))))))))))))*([^cu]|u([^cs]|s([^ct]|t([^co]|o([^cm]|m([^ce]|e([^cr]|r([^-c]|-([^cd]|d([^ce]|e([^ct]|t([^ac]|a([^ci]|i([^cl]|l([^cs]|s[^/c]))))))))))))))))*(c(c|u(c|s(c|t(c|o(c|m(c|e(c|r(c|-(c|d(c|e(c|t(c|a(c|i(c|l(c|sc)))))))))))))))*(u((s(t?|to(m?|me(r-?)?)))?|stomer-d(e?|et(a?|ai(ls?)?))))?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b2IDE8/2). Note I added `\n` only for the testing purposes since negated character classes can match newlines.